# Find the top ranked values by grouping through IDs while obtaining values across three excel sheets

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

Let's say I have three different sheets in an excel workbook and the contents and calculations in each sheet is described below.
Sheet 1
It has 3 columns named lookup_id, S1,S2.
[image]

Sheet 2

The initial sheet 2 contains only three columns: Name, ID, and lookup_id.

[image]

Step 1: The values in S1 and S2 are obtained from sheet 1 using vlookup function.

Step 2: The column "Sum" is sum of S1 and S2.

Step 3: The formula for column "Sum_by ID" is

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)>1,"",SUMIF($B$2:$B$10,B2,$F$2:$F$10))
```

What I want as final result is top 2 "Sum_by ID"  values as shown below in another sheet 3

Sheet 3

[image]

In sheet 3, the top 2 values are obtained using the formula below

```
=LARGE(Sheet2!$G$2:$G$10,A2)
```

Now, I want the result shown in Sheet 3 without completing step 1, step 2, and step 3 in Sheet 2.

Essentially, I don’t want any calculations in Sheet 2 and only use Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 (which originally contains first three columns) as reference and complete all steps in Sheet 3.

How can we achieve that?

If sheet 1 is as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(MAP(UNIQUE(B9:B14),LAMBDA(z,SUMPRODUCT(N(B9:B14=z),MAP(C9:C14,LAMBDA(x,SUM(XLOOKUP(x,A2:A7,B2:C7,0,0))))))),CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(A9:B14),2),CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(A9:B14),1)),1,-1),2)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How do I use the xlookup function when the lookup array I want has a different configuration. Like let’s say S1 in my case are column totals and S2 are row totals. Can I transpose S2?

Comment: I am not sure I get you. If your S1 is "vertical" and S2 is "horizontal" , wrap S2 with TOCOL, then HSTACK both arrays: HSTACK(S1column,TOCOL(S2row)) to get 2D array and use it instead of B2:C7 in XLOOKUP